# Бот не выводит ранее указанное значение

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot, sqlite3

Недавно начал кодить телеграмм ботов c базой данных на Python, используя библиотеки pytelegrambotAPI и sqlite3, и столкнулся с проблемой. Код не выводит значение, указаное пользователем. Код:

```
import sqlite3

token =                     
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

db = sqlite3.connect('data.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl(
    user_id integer,
    status string
)''')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
                 
def welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("test func")
    markup.add(item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - {1.first_name}!".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
            
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def main(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == "Назад":
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton("test func")

            markup.add(item1)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Назад".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == "test func":
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT `status` FROM `tbl` WHERE `user_id` = '{message.from_user.id}'")
            if cursor.fetchone() is None:
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                item1 = types.KeyboardButton("1а")
                item2 = types.KeyboardButton("2а")
                back = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")

                markup.add(item1, item2, back)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "test func".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
            
            elif cursor.fetchone() == '1':
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                back = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")

                markup.add(back)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "1".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
            elif cursor.fetchone() == "2":
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                back = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")

                markup.add(back)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "2".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == "1а":
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (?, ?)', (message.from_user.id, '1'))
            db.commit()
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            back = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")

            markup.add(back)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "1".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == "2а":
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (?, ?)', (message.from_user.id, '2'))
            db.commit()
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            back = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")

            markup.add(back)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "2".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

При выполнении test func первый раз код должен записать данные которые введёт юзер, и когда функция будет выполнятся второй раз он должен вывести значение, которое юзер указал в первый раз когда её использовал. Бот не выводит. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `fetchone` возвращает кортеж для существующих данных, поэтому ваша проверка, типа `cursor.fetchone() == '1'` (например, если статус `'1'`, то проверка была бы `('1',) == '1'`), всегда будет `False`

Я бы поменял код на вот так:

```
        elif message.text == "test func":
            sql = "SELECT `status` FROM `tbl` WHERE `user_id` = ?"
            result = cursor.execute(sql, [message.from_user.id]).fetchone()
            status = result[0] if result else None

            if status is None:
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                item1 = types.KeyboardButton("1а")
                item2 = types.KeyboardButton("2а")
                back = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")

                markup.add(item1, item2, back)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "test func".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)
            
            elif status == '1':
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                back = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")

                markup.add(back)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "1".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), reply_markup=markup)

            elif status == "2":
                ...
```